# Is it possible to control a digital camera from an iPad2?

Tags: ipad, camera

My 15 yr old daughter has cerebral palsy and has limited control of her hands which makes physical control of a camera difficult.

**Is it possible to connect a digital camera to her iPad 2?**

This would allow her to control the camera remotely from the iPad which she manages very well with the touchscreen. The built in camera is good however very limited due to difficulty holding it whilst taking the picture.

Answer (score 1):

There are applications for remote triggering more advanced DSLR cameras.

Like this one [DSLR Camera Remote HD for iPad](http://www.ononesoftware.com/products/dslr-camera-remote/)

Here is one more example: [Remote Shutter](http://eu.blueslr.com/RemoteShutter)

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off buying a remote trigger for your DSLR (if it is a DSLR you are using) these cost about £20 for a branded one and £7 for unbranded.